# fix bx_slider autoplay after select thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

**hello all**

i used bx slider to make content slider

my slider work fine but

i make it to work auto and use thumbs to show

in the start he work auto fine but

if i select thumbnail to show slider stop auto play

how can i fix it

i used this code

```
$(function(){

  var slider = $('#bxslider').bxSlider({
    controls: false,
    auto    : true ,
    captions: true
  });


  $('#Slides a').click(function(){
   var thumbIndex = $('#Slides a').index(this);

    slider.goToSlide(thumbIndex);


    $('#Slides a').removeClass('pager-active');

    $(this).addClass('pager-active');

    return false;
  });

  $('#Slides a:first').addClass('pager-active');
});
```

you can check the site here : [check the website if you don't understand me](http://www.7l7.com)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Second argument is for stopAuto.By default it is True so when you select thumbnail to show slider stop auto play.

```
slider.goToSlide(thumbIndex,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this as well.  Passing a boolean to goToSlide didn't work. To fix it, add this line directly after your call to slider.goToSlide(thumbIndex);

```
slider.startShow()
```

That will restart the "slide-show" starting with whatever slide it's on at the time.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem as well and fixed is very small.
Go to jquery.bxslider.js 
find **var clickPagerBind** and Add on last line `el.startAuto();`